# Does the 10% condition apply to geometric distributions?

Tags: binomial-distribution, independence, geometric-distribution, rule-of-thumb

I know that the 10% condition is required to assume independence in binomial settings. However, in a geometric setting where there is no fixed n-value, how would one determine independence?

I am a high school student so please don't be too harsh :)

source: https://web.ma.utexas.edu/users/mks/M358KInstr/TenPctCond.pdf

Comment: What "10% condition"?

Comment: https://web.ma.utexas.edu/users/mks/M358KInstr/TenPctCond.pdf

Comment: Please add the relevant information to the body of your question, not only link.

Comment: There's an implicit assumption here: namely, that one actually can assess independence by some kind of mathematical examination of the data. That's impossible; at most you can establish that a sample is not independent. E.g., the values in a sample of *any* size taken without replacement from a *finite* population will be negatively correlated and therefore not independent. (This lack of independence is rarely an issue until the sample exceeds 10% of the population.) Independence is determined partly by *how the subjects are selected for observation* and partly by assumptions you make.

Comment: This 'condition' is not a condition, its a rule of thumb some people use. The logic goes "In this situation the dependence under random sampling without replacement is small enough that *I'm* willing to approximate the correct calculations by treating these as if they were sampled *with* replacement". One person's willingness to accept that approximation doesn't impose any such requirement on the next person.